# Inserting user accepted inputs to database through flask

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask

I am accepting user input in html file, and sending it back to flask, using method POST and accepting it in a,b,c,d variables.
Now I am using the following query cur.execute("INSERT INTO Home VALUES(?,?,?,?)",a,b,c,d) to insert the values of a,b,c,d but I am getting an internal server error.
How to solve this problem?

Comment: i advise you to use sqlalchemy it's an excelent ORM. the internal server error could be raised caused by many errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is actually the code you're trying to execute:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO Home VALUES(?,?,?,?)",a,b,c,d)
```

then you must use a single list for the parameters list:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO Home VALUES(?,?,?,?)", [a,b,c,d])
```